# Php код в шорткоде Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Помогите пжлст с шорткодом, который бы вставлял нужное мне значение из файла `price.php`.

В этом файле указаны цены на товары в таком виде, он лежит в корне сайта

```
$price1=10;
$price2=11;
$price3=12;
```

и т.д.

Нужно выводить их с помощью шорткода

Добавил в `function` вот такой код

```
function price_sc($prc) {
     include 'calcs/pricesiding.php'; /* это файл где лежат переменные в таком виде  $price1=10; $price2=11; $price3=12;*/
     $prc_o=$prc; /* пробовал по всякому..  что тут написать что бы переменной $prc присвоилось значение $price1 ?*/
     return $prc_o;
}
add_shortcode('my_php_snippet', 'price_sc' );
```

Пишу такой шорткод

```
[my_php_snippet prc="$price1"]
```

Выдает `array`

Что нужно прописать в функции и как правильно передать в нее аргумент из шорткода? Я хочу обращаться по имени переменной, которая прописана в файле `price.php`.

Comment: `$prc = ltrim($prc, '$'); $prc_o=$$prc;`?

Comment: function price_sc($prc) {
     include 'calcs/pricesiding.php';
  $prc = ltrim($prc, '$'); 
  $prc_o=$$prc;
  return $prc;
}
add_shortcode('my_php_snippet', 'price_sc' );

Выдает ошибку Warning: ltrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in ***/themes/clubblog/functions.php on line 334 это строка  $prc = ltrim($prc, '$'); 
Вызываю вот так [my_php_snippet price="$price1"]

Comment: Сделайте `var_dump($prc);` перед `include 'calcs/pricesiding.php';` у вас в переменной массив находится, а не ожидаемая строка.

Comment: Вообще конечно так себе идея хранить цены в `php` файле. Не пробовали в БД писать?

Comment: Не умею пока, да и php вроде все наглядно, с комментариями, привык в общем. 
Поправил код 
function price_sc($prc) {
    var_dump($prc);
 include 'calcs/pricesiding.php';
  $prc = ltrim($prc, '$'); 
  $prc_o=$$prc;
  return $prc;
Теперь ругается на эту строку $prc = ltrim($prc, '$'); 
array(1) { ["title"]=> string(15) "$price1" } NULL
Warning: ltrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in ***/functions.php on line 336

Comment: Значит используйте `$prc = ltrim($prc['title'], '$'); $prc_o=$$prc;`

Comment: Не то значение возвращали, вместо return $prc; нужно было возвращать return $prc_o;, поправил, теперь цифирное значение выводится!!! Урра!! но над цифрой выводится вот такая строчка, что это?
array(1) { ["title"]=> string(15) "$price1" }

Comment: `var_dump($prc);` уберите, который прописали для вывода значения переменной `$prc` пользователю на страницу.

Comment: Ураа!!! Все заработало!!!! Спасибо огромное!!!! Я с утра с этим маюсь!! Супер! Пошел искать где плюсики ставят)))))

Comment: Не могу найти где плюсик/карму добавить вам)))